# Javascript audio function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm getting problems with this javascript code. In my site, I have an audio player in a div (this player is customized via js), and works perfectly, these are the instruction used to show the player in the page:

```
<div id="pers_player_footer">
<script src="../audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
<script>
audiojs.events.ready(function() {
var as = audiojs.createAll();
});
</script>
<audio src='../songs/empty.mp3' id='player' preload='auto' autoplay='true'/>
</div>
```

My player starts with an empty song. When I want to play a specific song the riproduci() function is performed and the link parameter is passed in order to change the src audio tag. This is my js function:

```
function riproduci(link) {
document.getElementById("pers_player_footer").innerHTML = "<script 
src='../audiojs/audio.min.js'></script>
<script>audiojs.events.ready(function() {var as = audiojs.createAll();});
</script><audio src='"+link+"' id='player' preload='auto' 
autoplay='true'/>";
}
```

This is the result: the new code is written correctly, the song starts playing properly, in my div the old player disapper but the new player doesn't apper leaving a blank space. What's wrong with this?

Comment: I don't think you need to have `<script 
src='../audiojs/audio.min.js'></script>` loaded again ... in fact, I'd put that tag outside of the target div, and remove it from the innerHTML text - though, to be perfectly honest, I think this whole method is flawed - what library is `audio.min.js`

Comment: I'd be inclined to look at [demo 6](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test6.html) to see how it handles a playlist - because you are doing things the hard way

Comment: the source to that can be found [here](https://github.com/kolber/audiojs/blob/master/demos/test5.html)

Comment: welcome to SO, if someone contributes time/effort to answer a question its implied that the person asking the question acknowledge/reward this effort by clicking the checkmark aside the answer and/or clicking the up arrow aside the answer ... this becomes a flag to other people reading the question that up arrowed answers are valid ... doing this makes this site more valuable to all ... take care

Answer (score 0):

A small change to your script as follows:

```
<div id="pers_player_footer">
<script src="../audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
<script>
    audiojs.events.ready(function() {
        var as = audiojs.createAll();
        // yeah I know, globals suck
        window.audio = as[0];
    });
</script>
<audio src='../songs/empty.mp3' id='player' preload='auto' autoplay='true'/>
</div>
```

then you can change your function to

```
function riproduci(link) {
    audio.load(link);
    audio.play();
}
```

yeah, I know globals suck, but without more context of the original code, this is as good as it gets

Comment: It doesn't work :( I don't know what's wrong with this

Comment: Sorry i wrote "windows" instead of "window", now it works! Thank you so much!